# Perl List::pairwise on Windows+ActiveState produces unexpected result

Tags: perl

I think that this Perl should produce ['c', undef] but on Windows 7, ActiveState 5.16 it produces: [].

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Test List::Pairwise
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

use v5.16;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use List::Pairwise qw(grepp mapp);
use Win32;

my $a = qr(\d+)x;
my $b = qr($a \. $a)x;

my %k = (a=>1, b=>2, c=>undef);
say dump([grepp {!$b} %k]);
say Win32::GetOSName();
say qx(perl -v);
```

Produces:

```
[]
Win7Home Premium (64-bit)

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Comment: `dump` doesn't do what you think it does: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dump.html

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, He's obviously using the builtin `dump` to get that output. He omitted a few directives from his code.

Comment: @ikegami I have been humbled for speaking too soon. I didn't know about Data::Dump, only Data::Dumper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't lexicalize the variables `$a` and `$b` with `my` or they lose their magic. `$a` and `$b` are actually special package variables that don't need to be declared for you to use them in functions like `sort` or `List::Pairwise::mapp`. If you do declare them, any function that relies on them will not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks.  Frustrating that there is no warning.

Comment: What would there be a warning? It's perfectly valid to create new variables with the same name as existing variables. e.g. `{ my $x = $x; # Protect $x  ... }`

Comment: @ikegami: when used in sort, there's a warning: `"my $a" used in sort comparison at ...`. Would be nice if `List::Pairwise` could also emit this warning.

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, Maybe, but it would have to plug itself into the parser to do that.

Comment: @ikegami: A 2nd best solution (a run time check) might be implemented using `PadWalker`, e.g `{ my $h = PadWalker::peek_my(0); if (exists $h->{'$a'} || exists $h->{'$b'}) { warn "You have \$a/\$b defined as a lexical!" } }`

Comment: @Slaven Rezic, That checks `mapp`'s caller, not the context in which its first arg was compiled. Then again, there's already other problems with `&mmap($code, ...)`

Comment: Well, builtin sort is also quite limited in its warning capabilities, it can also warn only if `$a` and `$b` are used directly in the comparison block.

Answer (score 2):

List::Pairwise sets variables `$a` and `$b` in the caller's package.

By using `my $b`, you told your call back to access that lexical variable instead `$::b`.

Aside from removing `my $b`, you could use the variable's full name or create a lexical directive to access the package variable.

```
grepp { !$::b } %k

grepp { our $b; !$b } %k

grepp { !our $b } %k
```